# After launching a process with subprocess.Popen and start_new_session, why does my terminal stop responding after Python exits?

Tags: python, terminal, subprocess, io-redirection

I have a Python script which launches a "detached" process and then exits, returning back to the terminal.

After I run this, and while the spawned process is running, the terminal becomes intermittently unresponsive. For example, I might have to press a character 4 times before it echoes in the terminal. After closing the spawned process (a separate window running a debugger), the terminal behavior goes back to normal.

I'm running on Ubuntu via WSL2 using the Windows Terminal.

```py
import subprocess
import sys
args = ['devenv.exe', sys.argv[1]]
subprocess.Popen(args, start_new_session=True, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
print('Happy debugging ...')
```

```bash
$ python launch_debugger.py
Happy debugging ...
$ # <-- hard to type now!?
# after closing the debugger window ...
$ # <-- now it works fine!
```

How do I make the terminal work normally while the spawned debugger is open?

Answer (score 0):

The spawned process must be reading from `stdin` periodically. By redirecting `stdin` to null when spawning the subprocess, the shell will get input from `stdin` reliably.

```py
import subprocess
import sys
args = ['devenv.exe', sys.argv[1]]
subprocess.Popen(args, start_new_session=True, stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
print('Happy debugging ...')
```

(Note this addition to the `Popen` arguments: **`stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL`**)